# Why my code can't delete previous words order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

i need help, i have this words in file:

```
world
car
house
school
```

i need reverse this words in the next way and delete previous words order all this in the same file:

```
school
house
car
world
```

this is my code but, doesn't delete previous words in file

```
dat = open("file.txt","r+")

for i in reversed(list(dat)):
   
    words= i.split()
    words = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    dat.write(words + "\n")

    
dat.close()
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Insert some useful `print` statements to trace values, and you'll see the problem.  Read the Stack Overflow posting guidelines, and you'll see where your posting falls short of expectations.

Comment: thanks but you didn't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all lines and go back to the starting point of the file and write the reversed content.

```
START_OF_FILE = 0
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.seek(START_OF_FILE)
    file.writelines(reversed(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it that way, this would be a solution(reading and writing separately using with statements:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as dat:
    words = list(dat.read().split('\n'))
    words.reverse()
    print(words)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as dat:
    string = ''
    for word in words:
        string += f'{word}'
        if words.index(word) != len(words)-1:
            string += '\n'
    dat.write(string)
```